# Query to get data, group by two columns and display multiple similar row by Client ID in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table as in below figure.

[image]

I want to query to this table so that I get data as follows:

[image]

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL_HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS, CLIENT_ID, `DAY` 
FROM timesheet_slave
GROUP BY CHARGE_ID, `DAY`;
```

And getting result as below:

[image]

How do I merge similar row with client id and get data as in following table?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Group by inconsistency, you select CLIENT_ID but group by CHARGE_ID. Should be same column in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this as shown below:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
       SUM(IF(`DAY`='Working', TOTAL_HOURS, 0)) AS TOTAL_WORKING_HOURS,   
       SUM(IF(`DAY`='Holiday', TOTAL_HOURS, 0)) AS TOTAL_HOLIDAY_HOURS
FROM timesheet_slave  
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID ;
```

Comment: you have a mistake  ... client:id and not charge_id

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos. I had to add some comma, brackets and it works perfectly.